# Appropriate data structure for time series

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on an application where I will need to maintain an object's trajectory. Basically, I'd like to have something like a sorted dictionary where the keys are times, and the values are positions. In addition, I'll be doing linear interpolation between existing entries. I've played a little bit with SortedDictionary in Grant Jenks's SortedContainers library, and it does a lot of what I want, but I'm wondering if there are solutions out there that are an even better fit? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org), there is [time series support available](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html).

Comment: Thank you, that does look interesting. The times I'll be using will be very basic - essentially simple floating point values starting at 0.0. Will pandas be overkill for that?

Comment: Using numpy itself may be overkill for that, if you're using numpy though, adding pandas is not too much overhead.

Comment: Well, there are other aspects of the application that are going to be more mathematically taxing (e.g. coordinate transforms), so I think I will be wanting numpy. I'll look more deeply at pandas, while giving other people a chance to answer...

Answer (score 1):

If your time interval is reliably constant, a list or of course a numpy array can be used.

Otherwise, you could look into ordered dictionaries in the collections module (std lib)

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html (Python 2)

  **class collections.OrderedDict([items])**

> ```
>     Return an instance of a dict subclass, supporting the usual dict
> ```
>
> methods. An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that
>   keys were first inserted. If a new entry overwrites an existing entry,
>   the original insertion position is left unchanged. Deleting an entry
>   and reinserting it will move it to the end.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. So, the time interval is not going to be constant, and there's no guarantee that I'm going to be entering positions in the order that I want them to be maintained (I might want to interpolate a position between two existing ones).